# How does Hyperledger Fabric achieve consensus without incentives?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, consensus

To the best of my knowledge, the Fisher-Lynch impossibility theorem states that consensus cannot be achieved even if there is one faulty node in the system.

Bitcoin is able to achieve consensus regardless by "incentivzing" the miners. But since hyperledger fabric is non-monetary, how is it able to gurrantee consensus despite the impossibility result?

Comment: This might be better suited for bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve consensus if you have assumptions on upper bounds of network delays. 
Fabric uses classical leader-based consensus that uses algorithms that have such assumptions.